# back/up button on Fragment toolbar not working after restore

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, back

The back/up button on my toolbar for my fragment works fine to pop the fragment when the user clicks it, but when I simulate Android killing the process in the background and then restoring it, the button no longer triggers the onOptionsItemSelected method. I can still go backward by pressing the hardware Back button, but this is no good.

This part is pretty standard code for setting up the toolbar in the onActivityCreated method of the fragment:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_overview);
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This also, for handling the button click:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // [coded that issues log statements, pops the fragment not shown]
    }
}
```

I reproduce the problem by:
1) opening the app
2) navigating to this fragment
3) pressing the hardware Home button
4) pressing the red X button (Terminate Application) in Android Studio
5) opening the app up again in the emulator using the app icon on the emulator screen. (I do not run the app again from Android Studio).
6) pressing the toolbar back button. (No result, no log statement; nothing).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your doing this in the onCreate Menthod:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_overview);
activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Try using onResume to refresh the action bar when the app is started again. Use this code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment's **onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** method 
add this one

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

In your Activity **override onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)** and **return false**

Then you should receive call in Fragment

**Another method** would be have a fragment object in your activity.

And when onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) of Activity gets called check if your fragment object is not null and then call the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) of fragment with the help your fragmentObject. make sure to return true if your fragment object is not null

e.g.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
   switch(item.getId()){
     case android.R.id.home:
      if(myFragObj != null){
             myFragObj.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
             return true
       }
     break;
   }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```